# How to make a view respond to a touch (not a tap)

Tags: swift, xcode

I am making a word search and have a grid of letters. I would like the user to be able to draw a finger across a row of letters, held in labels, and for those letters to respond in some way so that I can put the selected letters into an array.
I cannot find any way to make the letters respond to touches in this way.
I have tried recording the coordinates of the fingers (touchBegan, etc) and using them to work out where the letters are, but it is imprecise.
Is there any way I can get the cells in the grid to respond so that I can gather the information held in them?
I would prefer not to use taps as I feel users expect to drag their fingers across the grid.
I have been holding the letters in labels in collection view but am now trying to use a grid of textviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no. For a view. the only way you can detect a touch information is by overriding `touchesMoved` function. You have to calculate the location in order to see which cell the user is currently on. Also note that this function is triggered a lot when moving fingers. So you have to prevent duplicated values too.

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
        print(currentPoint)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I suspected as much